# Relativistic Inertial Reference for Charged Particles

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, charge, inertial-frames

Suppose two elétrons separated by a distance that their mutual interaction is so weak that can be regarded as null.

Suppose also they are under the effect of a constant and uniform electrical field and moving inside it in the same direction.

1. Is there acceleration in relation each other?
2. Do they feel the force of the electrical field, as much as somebody falling from a roof does not feel his own weight due to the supposed gravitational field caused by the mass of the earth?
3. Can the referential of each electron be regarded as inertial?
4. Can the electrical field be regarde as space time distortion for charge particles?

Comment: *constant electrical field* “Constant” means it doesn’t change with time. Is it also “uniform”, which means it doesn’t change with position?

Comment: Yes, I edited to put this piece of infomation in the text.

Answer (score 0):

> 1- Is there acceleration in relation each other?

No, because at each instant they have the same acceleration due to the electric field. This means that their relative acceleration is zero.

> 2- Do they feel the force of the electrical field, as much as somebody falling from a roof does not feel his own weight due to the supposed gravitational field caused by the mass of the earth?

Electrons are not sentient and do not “feel” anything. But they are accelerating in response to the electric force on them.

> 3- Can the referential of each electron be regarded as inertial?

No. They are accelerating.

> 4- Can the electrical field be regarde as space time distortion for charge particles?

No. There have been attempts to explain electromagnetic forces in the same way as gravity, but they have not been successful.

Comment: Lets say a negative charged body in outer space, jouneying in a linear path. Can an oberver know from anything in the body that it has note entered in an region of electrical field and its path changed, unles he looks outside?